# Unable to tag -- SVN, maven, Cygwin, spaces in the SVN repo path

Tags: maven, svn, cygwin, spaces

I am having problems running a subversion command from a cygwin prompt (driven from a maven script) on Windows 7. The command I am trying to run is invoked from a maven release:prepare  goal:

```
[INFO] Executing: cmd.exe /X /C "svn --non-interactive copy --file 
C:\cygwin64\tmp\maven-scm-1610151144.commit --revision 0 
"https://mysvn.server/svn_projects/Path Space/More Whitespace/src/tags/dest-0.1" 
"https://mysvn.server/svn_projects/Path Space/More Whitespace/src/tags/dest-0.1""
```

(I have inserted a few line breaks to make the command more readable).

The subversion command fails to tag with the following error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal 
org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.0:prepare (default-cli) 
on project dest: Unable to tag SCM
```

I have tried escaping spaces in my SCM path in the maven pom.xml with '\ ' instead of a simple ' '. Same result. So short of recreating a new path in SVN *without* spaces, is there a way to get around this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

URLs cannot contains spaces. What you need to do is *encode* the space as `%20`:

Instead of:

```
https://mysvn.server/svn_projects/Path Space/More Whitespace/src/tags/dest-0.1
```

Do

```
https://mysvn.server/svn_projects/Path%20Space/More%20Whitespace/src/tags/dest-0.1
```

Comment: In the maven pom.xml?

Comment: Yes. URIs are not suppose to contain certain characters. These characters are [percent-encoded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) in the URI. If the URI is in the pom.xml, then the URI in the POM should also be encoded too.

Comment: I took the easy out and removed the space from SVN's paths instead. I gather the reason tagging may have failed was because there was not tags sibling directory to trunk in SVN. Duh.

Comment: Banning spaces in file and directory names is always a good idea in development. I don't know enough on how Maven does SCM. I'm not a fan of having the build system directly interact with the version control system. In SVN, you can use `svn cp --parent` to create parent directories. For example, you have `$REPO/tags`, but not `$REPO/tags/4.3`. You can do this `svn cp $REPO/trunk/proj $REPO/tags/4.3/proj`, and Subversion will create both the `4.3` tag directory and the `proj` directory under it.